# Epsilon-delta proof of an absolute value function's limit for positive case

Tags: calculus

This question concerns this limit:
$$\lim_{x\to -2} |x - 2 |=4$$
Now, I was able to show that  can simply be set equal to ε when $x-2<0$ as follows:
$$||x-2|-4|< ε $$
$$|-(x-2)-4|< ε, x-2<0$$
$$|-x-2|<ε,$$
$$|x+2|<ε =  > |x+2| > 0$$
However, when $x+2\geq0,$ it appears that there is nothing left that I can do past this point:
$$||x-2|-4|<ε$$
$$|x-6|<ε, x-2\geq0$$
What may I be able to do to demonstrate that for all $ε>0$ there is a corresponding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate the possibility of $x - 2 \ge 0$ by forcing $\delta \le 4$, since
$$|x + 2| < \delta \le 4 \implies -4 < x + 2 < 4 \implies -8 < x - 2 < 0.$$
So, your choice of $\delta$ could be
$$\delta = \min \lbrace \varepsilon, 4 \rbrace.$$